# How to use flag-icon-css with angular2/4?

Tags: css, node.js, angular, svg, webpack

I want to use flag-icon-css with angular2/4 .
I setted up flag-icon-css using npm install flag-icon-css
and added ./node_modules/flag-icon-css/flag-icon.min.css in webpack styles.

looking at npm start output, it looks like all svg files are renamed :

```
  ad.a58027d893be40137b4e.svg    55.6 kB          [emitted]         
                            ae.9df491b1067fe429b98a.svg  273 bytes          [emitted]         
                            af.66d30d603494af84757f.svg    33.6 kB          [emitted]         
                            ag.0c113ee43f5e979f9e2b.svg  862 bytes          [emitted]         
                            ai.d6af3a0faf03775fead4.svg    58.2 kB          [emitted]         
                            al.7e21b4962e704ec70f96.svg    4.91 kB          [emitted]         
                            am.15d9b1b398267457715f.svg  242 bytes          [emitted]         
                            ao.ea04172c141ba985f772.svg    2.25 kB          [emitted]         
                            aq.2c772185d13c70791c11.svg    4.61 kB          [emitted]         
                            ar.738ab0020d69c00a1d1b.svg    4.56 kB          [emitted]         
                            as.5d5e432322a2db51180a.svg    11.5 kB          [emitted] 
.....
```

I suppose this is why I can not see flags ?

Answer (score 5):

In case somebody's still looking for it in Angular6, I added

```
"node_modules/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.css"
```

to angular.json's "styles" and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I am not completely sure it is the right way, but inserting the css file in my component was finally running.... :

styleUrls: ['../../../node_modules/flag-icon-css/css/flag-icon.css']